# Fibonacci Sequence using Datastage

Tags: fibonacci, datastage

I'm trying to get an output of Fibonacci sequence in Datastage. I am trying it with a row generator-->Transformer-->Sequential File. My data inside row generator is (0 and 1). I have no idea what to put in my transformer.

```
Data:0,1
```

The output should be `(0,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34)`. The number should be only up to 100, so I'm thinking of a loop variable.

Answer (score 2):

we can do this using three loop variables.

```
Name --> Derivation
varSum-->if (@ITERATION=1) then 0 else if (@ITERATION=2) then 1 else varFirst+varSecond
varFirst --> varSecond
varSecond --> varSum.
```

output will be `varSum`

from row generator u can get a single row to complete the job.

Answer (score 1):

Create 4 loop Variables in exact sequence as given below

Variable-->         Derivation

Output-->           ThirdValue

ThirdValue-->       FirstValue + SecondValue

FirstValue-->       If @ITERATION = 1 Then InputLink.InputValue Else SecondValue

SecondValue-->      ThirdValue

Give this looping condition ---> @ITERATION = 1 Or ThirdValue < 100

Take Output to your output file column

Comment: Note, You just need the input data:(0) instead of Data:(0,1)
So please adjust your Row generator to give only 1 row as output with value 0